# Hibernate - How to persist only the parent, keeping the children as they are

Tags: java, hibernate

Can someone please help me understand how to configure hibernate to do what i want.

I have a parent entity "Appartment" with a List of "Room"s as children.
I have a form to edit "Appartment"s and within that form i have listed all of the children "Room"s just for informative purposes. Rooms are added and edited in a separate form.

So because i am listing the rooms in the appartment-form i have set lazyloading to false:

```
    @OneToMany
@JoinColumn (name = "appartmentId")
@LazyCollection (LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Room> room;
```

But if I edit an appartment and store it, all the appartments rooms suddenly dissappear. In the database they are not deleted, but dereferenced (as in appartmentId = null).

So how can I configure hibernate to only persist my Appartment-object. And not touch the children at all?

This is my save-action:

```
public String save() throws Exception {
    boolean isNew = (appartment.getAppartmentId() == null);

    appartment = appartmentManager.save(appartment);

    String key = (isNew) ? "appartment.added" : "appartment.updated";
    saveMessage(getText(key));

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you reconstructing the `Appartment` object before you store it? It seems like you are removing the `Room`s from your list, either explicitly or by creating a new, empty list.

Comment: I just added my save-metode above. As you can see i do not really do anything to the appartment object before storing it..

Comment: where does `appartment` come from? (side note: it's spelled *apartment* ;-)

Comment: Well, being fairly new to struts2, i can only imagine it should be the same object that are being set in the edit() method. The edit-method tests the id for null and if not null gets the appartment-object from database. If null it creates new instance. For this particular case the id will never be null because it is only used for editing, not creating new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is really simple. No need to repopulate your children, or create separate DTO's.

If you are never going to persist the children just add insertable=false, updatable=false to your joincolumn annotation. Like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn (name = "appartmentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Room> room;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what i wanted. Easy, clean and straight to the point!

Comment: @user829237: You realize that this means you can *never* add a room to an apartment by just adding it to the list of rooms, right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't disable lazy fetching in a mapping. Use [fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) for performance tuning.
2. Hibernate will only remove the Rooms from an Apartment if you tell it to save/update an Apartment that has no Rooms in it.

Comment: Thanks for this! 1. Just implemented fetching strategy and it works great. 2. When the save-action is called, all rooms are gone from the appartment-object. It seems so unneccesary to do yet another call to the db to repopulate the Room-list just so it wont be touched when persisting the appartment. Is this really how it is supposed to be?

Comment: I assume you're trying to create a new instance, manually set the primary key property, and then save it. That's destined for failure in many different ways. The correct way to update an entity is to first load it, then make changes to it within a transaction.

Comment: The point im trying to make is: I just want to update the appartment-object. That equals one db-statement (update appartment set ....etc). It should not be required to load all children, just so the parent can be saved when the children is to remain untouched..

Comment: With lazy loading, you don't load all the children.

Comment: I dont know what i'm missing here. But my experience is that when the form is submitted (in save-action) the method appartment.getRooms() will return null. So in order to get it to not return null i would have to first do: appartment.setRooms(appartmentHibernateImpl.get(appartmentId).getRooms(); Thus making one extra db-call. Is this not correct?

Comment: Again, if you're talking about an update, then the appropriate first step is to load the apartment using hibernate. If you mean that immediately after loading, apartment.getRooms() returns null, then you have a problem in your mappings, and to answer your question, no, it's not correct that you should have to manually load the rooms separately from the apartment. The whole point of an ORM is to manage these kinds of relationships for you.

Comment: I've got an example project out on github that shows basic usage of a hibernate one-to-many mapping. You can clone it with `git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed tmp` and then look at the module named hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-with-join-column or [take a look at it on github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-with-join-column). It shows that saving a parent entity and then loading it loads the mapped children as well.

Comment: Aha. I think we have a misunderstanding each other. Your example is good, i know the basics you are trying to show me. What i'm talking about is doing it a struts2 action. You see, when the form is loaded, the action-method edit() is run and this method populates the appartment-object (with children). So far so good. Then the form is submitted, action-method save() is run and this method do NOT reload the appartment object. So now we have an appartment object without children. I could reload the children, then save, but that seems unneccessary. Are you getting what im saying?

Comment: What I hear you saying is that your save() creates a new Apartment object and you go and save it directly. My answer is still the same: you *must* use a persistent object and modify it rather than creating a new one and saving it. Either take the Apartment you loaded in edit() and store it in the HTTP Session and reuse it, or load it again in the edit() method. It doesn't matter whether you're doing it in Struts or not. Doing it the way you're doing it is contrary to how ORMs work, and it *will* lead to more problems in the future.

Comment: aha. so i guess thats my missing link here! I need to take my object and store it in the http-session for reuse. I have actually been thinking about that for ages, but i could not find an answer as to how to store it in the session. Do you know where to find a tutorial?

Comment: You should probably read ["Sessions and transactions"](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) and ["Open Session in View"](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView). The latter specifically deals with ["long conversations"](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView#What_about_the_extended_Session_pattern_for_long_Conversations). Note however that it's much more common--and a lot simpler--to just load the object again on the next request. I don't understand why you seem to be so hard-set against that option.

Comment: Ok. I surrender. I'll reload the object. :) Im just used to programming with stored procedures and i dont like unneccesary calls to the database.

Comment: Your life will be much simpler this way :) Treat database calls as cheap until proven otherwise. Trying to avoid them is just a form of optimization, and optimization should always be put off until there's a proven performance problem.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using persistent entities, consider using DTOs (you can call them a page model in the case of web pages). They can give you a flexibility to depict information you want and show it in the format you want. But you should pay for this - you're adding new classes to your system and you have to come up with a way to transform entities to DTOs and backward.

Comment: There's no reason to have two mapping layers when one is enough.

Comment: I didn't say anything about mapping layer. DTO/VO is a layer for handy depicting or sending data depending on the purpose. Usually it's not enough simply having persistent entities for everything, you should have classes that carry information specifically for particular purpose.

Comment: Fair enough, but that doesn't really pertain to the question.

Comment: Instead of raping Hibernate, in most cases it's better to define DTOs. This is not an answer to the question, but rather a solution to the outlined problem.

Comment: I might just look into this. Even though it feels completly unneccessary to write extra DTO's just so not the children are touched. Sometimes i wish Hibernate was never invented, and i was not required to use it.

Comment: If you work with it tighly for a year, you'll understand how much it helps and how much it does for you :) It really does a looot of things you would write yourelf if you used JDBC. So just enjoy ;)