# Java/Hibernate - How to disable joined entity update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I want to save entity bellow to database via `entityManager.persist(myEntity)`. However child's (`ProjectEntity`) child is updated too. How can I disable update of child entities update. 
Thank you.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")    
public class MyEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)         
        private Integer id;

        @Column
        private String user;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
        private ProjectEntity project;
}
```

Comment: You can find the solution from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071886/hibernate-how-to-persist-only-the-parent-keeping-the-children-as-they-are)

Answer (score 0):

Please update following code in your entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private ProjectEntity project;
```

Comment: `orphanRemoval ` is unfortunately not supported for `@ManyToOne` annotation

Comment: Use it at childs collection