# Loading list like @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Good Morning,

I'm building a REST api and I would like to know how I can solve a paradigm, because in recent days I've researched a lot about bidirectional mapping @OneToMany and @ManyToOne

I have the following hypothetical situation:

a person and their contacts

When I save the person, I need to validate some contact information, and I would like to save the person and the contact list separately, not the way Hibernate does that saves everything simultaneously, but I find @OneToMany extremely useful for loading the Contact list simply by selecting the Person entity.

what would you like to know:

1. Is there a way to load the contact list with an annotation other than @OneToMany, where I would indicate the join and hibernate would load the data in a similar way to @OneToMany, without impacting my criteria?
2. Is there a setting for @OneToMany to be read Only, that is, the moment I persist the parent (Person) does nothing with the childs (Contacts)?

the solution at [Hibernate - How to persist only the parent, keeping the children as they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071886/hibernate-how-to-persist-only-the-parent-keeping-the-children-as-they-are), did not solve my problem,

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id      
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  
  @Column(name = "i_person")  
  private Long iPerson;

  @Column  
  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person") // here I tried several things, however nothing works as I need, @JoinColumn, Several cascade types  
  @OrderBy("iContact ASC")  
  private List<Contact> contacts;
  
  @Anything // some annotation that only makes the "select" in the list of contacts to occur along with the select that hibernate does  
  private List<Contact> contacts2;

  // getters and setters ...
}

@Entity
public class Contatp implements Serializable {
  @Id      
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
  @Column(name = "i_contact")  
  private Long iContact;

  @JoinColumn(name = "i_person")  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
  private Person person;

  
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "contact_type")
  private TypeContact typeContact;
  
    
  @Column(name = "phone_mail_other")  
  private String phoneMailOther;

// getters and setters ...
}
```

EDIT

example:

```
"person": {
    "iPerson":2,
      "nome": "Carlos",
      "contacts": [
          {
              "iContact": 5,
        "typeContact":"P",
              "phoneMailOther": "xyz"
          },
          {
              "iContact": 6,
        "typeContact":"P",
              "phoneMailOther": "zyx"
          }
      ]
  }
```

I want it to work like this:

```
...

//rooutine to validade person
...
//persist person
Person person = jpaRepositoryPerson.save(person);



for(Contact c: person.getContacts()){
  //validate contacts
  //check if the id of the infomed contact is of the person, etc.,

  c.setPerson(person);

  c = jpaRepositoryContact.save(c);

}
```

trys catchs its fine.

but would like the contact list to be loaded with

```
...
List <Person> persons = em.createQuery (personQuery).getResultList ()
...
```

EDIT 2

Assuming as a continuation of the above example, if before the persistence has been excluded the contact 5 when trying to make a put of the same json of the example will be presented the following message:

```
error
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.example.Contat with id 5; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.Contat with id 5

trace
0 = {StackTraceElement@15593} "org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@15594} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:230)"2 = {StackTraceElement@15595} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@15596} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124)"
4 = {StackTraceElement@15597} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92)"
5 = {StackTraceElement@15598} "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257)"
6 = {StackTraceElement@15599} "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140)"
7 = {StackTraceElement@15600} "org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)"
8 = {StackTraceElement@15601} "org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)"
9 = {StackTraceElement@15602} "org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)"
10 = {StackTraceElement@15603} "org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457)"
11 = {StackTraceElement@15604} "org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:358)"
12 = {StackTraceElement@15605} "org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:551)"
13 = {StackTraceElement@15606} "org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:699)"
14 = {StackTraceElement@15607} "org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:163)"
15 = {StackTraceElement@15608} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:393)"
16 = {StackTraceElement@15609} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:327)"
17 = {StackTraceElement@15610} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)"
18 = {StackTraceElement@15611} "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)"
19 = {StackTraceElement@15612} "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:901)"
20 = {StackTraceElement@15613} "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)"
21 = {StackTraceElement@15614} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
22 = {StackTraceElement@15615} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
23 = {StackTraceElement@15616} "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
24 = {StackTraceElement@15617} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
25 = {StackTraceElement@15618} "org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)"
26 = {StackTraceElement@15619} "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy206.merge(Unknown Source)"
27 = {StackTraceElement@15620} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
28 = {StackTraceElement@15621} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
29 = {StackTraceElement@15622} "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
30 = {StackTraceElement@15623} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
31 = {StackTraceElement@15624} "org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)"
32 = {StackTraceElement@15625} "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy206.merge(Unknown Source)"
33 = {StackTraceElement@15626} "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:493)"
34 = {StackTraceElement@15627} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
35 = {StackTraceElement@15628} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
36 = {StackTraceElement@15629} "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
37 = {StackTraceElement@15630} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
38 = {StackTraceElement@15631} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)"
39 = {StackTraceElement@15632} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)"
40 = {StackTraceElement@15633} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)"
41 = {StackTraceElement@15634} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
42 = {StackTraceElement@15635} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)"
43 = {StackTraceElement@15636} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)"
44 = {StackTraceElement@15637} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
45 = {StackTraceElement@15638} "org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)"
46 = {StackTraceElement@15639} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
47 = {StackTraceElement@15640} "org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)"
48 = {StackTraceElement@15641} "org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)"
49 = {StackTraceElement@15642} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
50 = {StackTraceElement@15643} "org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)"
51 = {StackTraceElement@15644} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
52 = {StackTraceElement@15645} "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)"
53 = {StackTraceElement@15646} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
54 = {StackTraceElement@15647} "org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)"
55 = {StackTraceElement@15648} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
56 = {StackTraceElement@15649} "org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)"
57 = {StackTraceElement@15650} "org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)"
58 = {StackTraceElement@15651} "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)"
59 = {StackTraceElement@15652} "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.save(Unknown Source)"
```

this occurs at the moment of the person's persistence

Comment: What you're looking for is... OneToMany. You need to clarify what you mean by "I would like to save the person and the contact list separately, not the way Hibernate does that saves everything simultaneously". I think you misunderstand how Hibernate works.

Comment: Hi, tanks, look if my new edit makes it clearer

Comment: Not really. i don't really see what prevents you from doing that (or at least almost that: you shouldn't use the persistent entities (part of the persistence layer) to represent what a client sends you over HTTP (presentation/communication layer). So, define DTOs to represent what the client sends you over HTTP, and implement the logic you want to save what needs to be saved, the way you want to.

Comment: It's ok, I figured I'd have to change the logic for that situation.

About that:
@Anything // some annotation that only makes the "select" in the list of contacts to occur along with the select that hibernate does
   private List <Contacts> contacts2;

would you know

Comment: I'm using DTOs but in some cases i need get the id generated

Comment: I'm using DTOs, and I always want the IDs to be generated. Why would using DTOs prevent you from using auto-generated IDs?

Comment: It does not prevent, I use the auto-generated, in this case it is update (put / patch)

Comment: Is there a question/problem hidden somewhere that I don't understand?

Comment: Let's say that we would focus on "select" when loading the person entity, is there a way to bring the contacts together, without customizing the query, as @OneToMany does when querying the person?

Comment: My whole point, from the start is that you should simply use OneToMany. That's what it does, that's what it's for. Using a OneToMany does not prevent you from first saving the person, or to validate the contacts, or to use DTOs, or to generate IDs.

Comment: "Using a OneToMany does not prevent you from first saving the person", how to save the person first and then save the contact?

Comment: Well, you do just that. You save the person, then you save the contacts. `Person p = new Person(); personRepo.save(p); Contact c = new Contact(); c.setPerson(p); contactRepo.save(c); p.addContact(c);`

Comment: Basically would be what I do in the edit portion right?

Comment: but some problems have happened ... :(

Comment: If you have "some problems", and want help with those problems, post the relevant code, tell us what you expect it to do, precisely, and what it does instead, precisely. Include complete and exact error messages.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit with a simple simulation of what I'm doing, entities are large and somewhat complex, but it's easy to simulate with smaller entities.

Comment: Hi, finish edit

Comment: The contact ID is supposed to be auto-generated. So, when you ask JPA to save a contact with a given ID, it assumes that this is not a new contact (since it already has an ID). So it tries updating the contact with ID 5. But this contact doesn't exist. So it fails. That has nothing to do with OneToMany.

Comment: Good morning, I solved my problems by putting autoFlush as "FlushMode.COMMIT" so it only synchronizes the data after my complete manipulation of the data. 
Tanks for attention!