# Unidirectional ManyToMany readonly relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity *Student* and an entity *Course*. One student can be associated to 0 or more *Courses*. Viceversa, one *Course* can have associated 0 or more *Students*.

*Student* entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "studentId",
                    referencedColumnName = "id",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "courseId",
                    referencedColumnName = "id",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false)
    )
    private Collection<Course> courses;
}
```

*Course* entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private Collection<Student> students;
}
```

and the inverse association in the entity *Course*.

Both of those 2 *@ManyToMany* associations should be readonly.
My problem is that when I try to save a *Student* Hibernate tries to update also the associated collection.

Here's what hibernate logs on a student update:

```
Hibernate: 
/* delete collection model.student.courses */ 
delete from `student_course` 
where `studentId`=?

Hibernate: 
/* insert collection row  */
insert into `student_course` (`studentId`, `courseId`) 
values (?, ?)
```

As you can see hibernate is trying to update **also** the table that stores the associations between the two entities.
Those are the queries that I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried cascading?

Comment: @Anas yes I've tried it

Comment: Can you tell me which cascading you used

Comment: I've used the cascading ALL. Nevertheless in my opinion the correct approach should be to avoid using any cascading type.

Comment: All would not work as All includes persist and delete so it would perform the respective operations, I'd suggest try using cascade Refresh only and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried REFRESH but hibernate is still generating deletions and insertions for that association.

Comment: Allright... let me look for further solutions as well

Comment: I found another solution, apparently making your relationships transient will stop their persist behaviour on database. Try making the relationship `@Transient` and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154640/2819935

Comment: I cannot make it transient otherwise hibernate doesn't initialise the relationship on select.

Comment: Please, provide classes `Student` and `Course` with related  to mapping fields and annotations.

Comment: @v.ladynev I've updated my question providing the classes I'm using. The Data annotation is of Lombock and it automatically creates getter and setters.

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but have you considered not using lombok, and just write getter and setters with an IDE template?

Comment: @VitorSantos yes I've tried, the problem is not Lombok

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078678/2819935. I can already see you have mentioned the keywords informed in the link. Can you try changing the fetch type as suggested in the answer and also I'd like to know why you have used `@JoinTable` annotation instead of simple `@JoinColumn`

Comment: @Anas because I'm using a ManyToMany relationship not a OneToMany. The associations between the 2 entities are stored in specific table, so I need to have multiple JoinColumns

Comment: @desoss understood. I mapped many to many in a different way ... Since I created a third table. I generated a separate entity and mapped both single entities in a one-to-many to that third table. In your case the third java class should be StudentCourse and the collection of Course would be changed to collection of StudentCourse

Comment: @desoss I have also tried and tested `@Transient` in entity and while fetching it does get initialized. Can you also apply that and check?

Answer (score 0):

Student class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name="STUDENT_COURSE"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
        }
    )
private List<Course> courses;
```

Course class :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses")
private List<Student> students;
```

As you khnow, from the JPA 2.0 spec, the defaults fetch are:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

And in the latest version of hibernate fetch type is eager by deafult for all the mappings but if we are using JPA annotations then it aligns with JPA defaults.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Hibernate still perform DELETE and INSERT queries or on a save of a Student or on a save of a Course. While I want 2 readonly associations.

Comment: @desoss even if you try with fetch= Lazy ?

Comment: Sure, I'm obtaining that query on a save(Student) (or on save(Course) depending on where the mappedBy is) not on the retrieval of the entities

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a `list` is ordered whereas a `set` is not. The generalized code for updating a list seems to assume that you wish to preserve that order and so it must delete the entire List of relations and reinsert it fresh to preserve the order through the relation PK ids. This would be explicitly true if you added an `@OrderBy` annotation on the join property. In a set this is not necessary so it can just do an insert.

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class E1 {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<E2> e2s;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class E2 {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="e2s")
    Set<E1> e1s;
```

And to use them:

```
E1 e1 = new E1();
E2 e2 = new E2();
Set<E2> es2 = new HashSet<>();
es2.add(e2);
e1.setE2s(es2);

em.persist(e1);
em.persist(e2);
tx.commit();

// now modify the list
em.clear();

// fetch relations to avoid lazy fetch exception
e1 = em.createQuery("select e from E1 e left outer join fetch e.e2s where e.id = :id", E1.class)
        .setParameter("id", 1L)
        .getSingleResult();

tx.begin();
e2 = new E2();
e1.getE2s().add(e2);
em.persist(e2);
em.merge(e1);
tx.commit();
```

This gives me the following logs

```
create table E1_E2 (e1s_id bigint not null, e2s_id bigint not null, primary key (e1s_id, e2s_id))
create table E1 (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
create table E2 (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
alter table E1_E2 add constraint FKky9vffxlkk0u9t0ynqfsvanrt foreign key (e2s_id) references E2
alter table E1_E2 add constraint FKgnbwe4qtab0mt1caqxrrp8gqd foreign key (e1s_id) references E1
insert into E1 (id) values (default)
insert into E2 (id) values (default)
insert into E1_E2 (e1s_id, e2s_id) values (?, ?)
select e1x0_.id as id1_2_0_, e2x2_.id as id1_4_1_, e2s1_.e1s_id as e1_3_0__, e2s1_.e2s_id as e2_3_0__ from E1 e1x0_ left outer join E1_E2 e2s1_ on e1x0_.id=e2s1_.e1s_id left outer join E2 e2x2_ on e2s1_.e2s_id=e2x2_.id where e1x0_.id=?
insert into E2 (id) values (default)
insert into E1_E2 (e1s_id, e2s_id) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: The problem is that I want both ManyToMany relationships to be readonly. Hence I don't want to see any INSERT (nor any DELETE) for the children entities when a persist the parent entity occurs.

Comment: Yea that makes. A read only persistent object. Good luck with that. Say hi to Putin for me.

Comment: When I save A I just want that A would be saved not also also its children. This is the behaviour of the inverse ManyToMany relation (the one with mappedBy field).

Comment: That's nice, I guess, since I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: In your example if you try to persist a E2 entity with some e1s entries you shouldn't see any insert(/delete) into E1. I want this behaviour in both entities.

Comment: Persist or merge? If you define a relationship and add elements to it why wouldn't it persist? E1 is the owner so any relations added to it will be persisted. E2 is not the owner so it will ignore any new relations added there. The `e1s` set in E2 is for query only and makes the mapping bidirectional. You can't have a read-only unidirectional relation because the owner is by definition responsible for persisting the entity and its relations.

Comment: How I manage the update of the associations is out of the scope of this question. But you are right it seems that I cannot have a readonly owner of ManyToMany relationship even if the JoinColumns have insertable=false and updatable=false.

Comment: I assume those settings are overridden by the ownership and probably not intended for such purposes.