# How do i persist the parent entity without updating the child entity where they have many to many relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I have a parent entity A which has many to many realtion with entity B and entity C which are mapped in A_B table and A_C table . While persisting I want to persist only A,A_B and A_c without persisting B and C .
If I **dont use** **cascadetype.all** i get "**object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing**" error . 
**If i use cascade.all all the tables gets updated.**

This is my parent Entity Student(getters and setters are present but not shown)

```
@Entity
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int studentId;
......
...... 
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "student_preferredCountry",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name 
= "studentId"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "countryId"))
private Set<Country> countries;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "student_preferred_course",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name 
= "studentId"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "courseId"))
private Set<Course> courses;
```

This is my child entity  Course

```
@Entity
public class Course {
private String courseName;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int courseId;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
private List<Student> coursestudents;
```

This is my another child entity Country

```
@Entity
public class Country {
@Id
private int countryId;
private String countryName;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "countries")
private List <Student> students;
```

This is how i persist

```
public boolean studententry(@RequestBody Student stud){
studentRepository.save(stud);
```

This is the sample json request

```
{

"studentFname": "fdfd",
"studentMname": "dfdf",
"studentLname": "fdf",
"studentFatherName": "fd",
"studentMotherName": "dfd",
"studentEmail": "dfd",
"studentAddress": "df",
"studentPhone": "df",
"countries": [
    {
        "countryId": "1",
        "countryName": "aus"
    },
    {
        "countryId": "2",
        "countryName": "newz"
    }
],
"courses": [
    {
        "course_id": "1",
        "course_name": "IELTS"
    },
    {
        "course_id": "2",
        "course_name": "TOEFL"
    }
    ]

}
```

Basically i want to add all student properties, student_courses,student_country whithout persisting on course and country table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate - How to persist only the parent, keeping the children as they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071886/hibernate-how-to-persist-only-the-parent-keeping-the-children-as-they-are)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `cascade=ALL` does the opposite of what you want. `ALL=PERSIST,MERGE,REFRESH,DETACH,REMOVE`, so it basically says 'whenever I store, update, or delete the `Student`, do the same with all the associated `Courses`', among other things.

For `@ManyToMany` associations, `PERSIST`, `MERGE`, `REMOVE` don't make a lot of sense. You might want to keep `REFRESH` and `DETACH`, but you would be well advised to get rid of the rest.

Secondly, removing `MERGE` has the side effect of getting `TransientObjectException`. This happens because you are trying to save a detached entity that references other detached entities. You may be calling `repository.save(student)`, but this only merges the `Student` entity, and the referenced `Course` entities remain detached.

To solve this problem, you need to replace the detached entity instances with managed entity instances by the same ids:

```
Set<Courses> managedCourses = new HashSet<>();
for (Course course : stud.getCourses()) {
    managedCourses.add(courseRepository.getOne(course.getId()));
}
stud.setCourses(managedCourses);
studentRepository.save(stud); //no TransientObjectException this time!
```

(note the use of `getOne()` in a loop; you may be tempted to use `findAllById()`, thinking it would be more performant, but the benefit of `getOne()` is that it does not fetch the associated entity state from the data source. `getOne()` is provided by `JpaRepository` specifically with this use case in mind: to establish associations between entities)

Finally, I can see `stud` is annotated with `@RequestBody`, suggesting we're in a `Controller` class here. For the above approach to work, you want to wrap the entire method in a transaction using `@Transactional`. Since transactional controller methods are not exactly good practice, I'd suggest extracting the body of the `studententry` method to a separate `@Transactional`, `@Service`- annotated bean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch from `@ManyToMany` into `@OneToMany`.

Then you can put the cascading on `Student` and omit that in the `StudentCourse` and `StudentCountry` entities.

The only downside is that you need to create intermediate entites for those linking tables:

**Student**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student")
private Set<StudentCourse> courses;
```

**StudentCourse**

```
@ManyToOne
private Student student;

@ManyToOne
private Course course;
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
public class Course {
private String courseName;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int courseId;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
private List<StudentCourse> coursestudents;
```

You would need to alter the incomming json object accordingly to support those intermediate entities ofc.